# Remove an appended item and add a new appended item

Tags: jquery

So, I'm looking to click a link, change the text, and then when you click it again it changes back. I'm currently doing this by append the text I want. However, I'm not able to change the text back to the original. This is what I have so far... any help would be much appreciated.

**HTML**

```
<a class="link" href="">
   <span class="icon icon-chat"></span>
   <span>Link</span>
</a>
```

**JS**

```
$('.link').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var $linkClicked = $('<span>Link Clicked</span>');

    $(this).toggleClass('active').append($linkClean).find('span').first().remove();

    $linkClicked.on('click', function() {
        $(this).remove();
        $('.link').append('<span>Link</span>');
    });
});
```

Comment: May I answer this question in vanilla JS?  I could do it SUPER easily . . .

Comment: Have you tried it with `jQuery`'s `detach()` function? http://api.jquery.com/detach/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to do it with comments in each step to show what is happening:

```
$('.link').on('click', function() {
    // variables holding sample text
    var textNormal = "Link";            
    var textClicked = "Link Clicked";
    // get text from the link
    var text = $(this).text();
    // if text is normal, make it clicked, otherwise make it normal
    if(text === textNormal) {
        $(this).text(textClicked);
    } else {
        $(this).text(textNormal);   
    }
});
```

[**`jsFiddle`**](http://jsfiddle.net/5dhwb2dk/)

Answer (score 0):

If you can use vanilla JavaScript, it can be done very easily.  I would use something like below:

```js
function changeText(idElement) {
  var element = document.getElementById('element' + idElement);
  if (idElement === 1 || idElement === 2) {
    if (element.innerHTML === 'Read More...') element.innerHTML = 'Close';
    else {
      element.innerHTML = 'Read More...';
    }
  }
  
  return false;
}
```

```html
<a id="element1" href="#" onClick="javascript:return changeText(1)">Read More...</a>
<a id="element2" href="#" onClick="javascript:return changeText(2)">Read More...</a>
```

Hope this helps!